# Binding with checkbox (select all)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want to implement a checkbox which functions as a select-all / unselect-all checkbox but I am getting some problems with the binding. I am not really new to XAML and WPF so it is a mistery to me why my code is not working. I hope you can help. This is what I am doing:

First of all, I use MVVMLight and the event-to-command tags.

My view is called SetupView.xaml and my view-model is called SetupViewModel.cs

```
public class SetupViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<FilterOptions> m_informationToShow;
    private FilterOptions m_currentSelection;

    public List<FilterOptions> InformationToShow
    {
        get { return m_informationToShow; }
        set
        {
            m_informationToShow = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("InformationToShow");
            RaisePropertyChanged("InformationToShowCount");
        }
    }

    public FilterOptions CurrentSelection
    {
        get { return m_currentSelection; }
        set
        {
            m_currentSelection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSelection");
        }
    }
}
```

The FilterOptions-object is my model object. Because you will need some of it it to understand the problem, here it show the part you need to understand the problem:

```
public class FilterOptions
{
    private string m_projectName;

    private BugsFilter m_bugsFilter;
    private BuildsFilter m_buildsFilter;
    private ChangeSetsFilter m_changeSetsFilter;
    private ProgressInfoFilter m_progressInfoFilter;
    private RisksFilter m_risksFilter;

    private bool m_projectHealthFilter;

    public bool AllFilterValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_bugsFilter.AtLeastOneFieldEnabled() ||
                m_buildsFilter.AtLeastOneFieldEnabled() ||
                m_changeSetsFilter.AtLeastOneFieldEnabled() ||
                m_progressInfoFilter.AtLeastOneFieldEnabled() ||
                m_risksFilter.AtLeastOneFieldEnabled() ||
                m_projectHealthFilter
                )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == false)
            {
                m_bugsFilter.NoInformation();
                m_buildsFilter.NoInformation();
                m_changeSetsFilter.NoInformation();
                m_progressInfoFilter.NoInformation();
                m_risksFilter.NoInformation();
                m_projectHealthFilter = false;
            }
            else
            { 
                m_bugsFilter.CompleteInformation();
                m_buildsFilter.CompleteInformation();
                m_changeSetsFilter.CompleteInformation();
                m_progressInfoFilter.CompleteInformation();
                m_risksFilter.CompleteInformation();
                m_projectHealthFilter = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I will proceed with my view:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:SetupViewModel x:Key="thisViewModel"></viewModels:SetupViewModel>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProjectEntryTemplate">
        <Border Margin="75,20,5,0">
            <CheckBox Name="naam" Content="{Binding ProjectName}"
                      FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                      FontWeight="Light"
                      FontSize="24"
                      IsChecked="{Binding AllFilterValues}"
                      DataContext="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ProjectListItemCheckedChanged, Source={StaticResource thisViewModel}}"
                                             PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ProjectListItemCheckedChanged, Source={StaticResource thisViewModel}}"
                                             PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
        </Border> 
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

As you can see, I have a datatemplate which I am using in a listbox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding InformationToShow}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectEntryTemplate}" 
                            SelectedIndex="0"
                            BorderThickness="0">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionListboxChanged}" 
                                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ListBox>
```

Besides from that, I have in the same window, in another grid on the right side, a lot of checkboxes. They all correspond to a given filter from the FilterOptions object. This is what I am doing in my view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5">
                        <CheckBox Name="activeBugs" Content="Active bugs"
                                  FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                  FontWeight="Light"
                                  FontSize="22"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentSelection.BugsFilter.ActiveBugs}">
                        </CheckBox>

                        <CheckBox Name="resolvedBugs" Content="Resolved bugs"
                                  FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                  FontWeight="Light"
                                  FontSize="22"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentSelection.BugsFilter.ResolvedBugs}"/>
                        <CheckBox Name="bugTrend" Content="Bug trend"
                                  FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                  FontWeight="Light"
                                  FontSize="22"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentSelection.BugsFilter.BugTrend}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Last but not least, this are the command functions which I have in my view-model:

```
RelayCommand m_selectionChanged;
    public ICommand SelectionListboxChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_selectionChanged == null)
                m_selectionChanged = new RelayCommand(param => SelectionListboxChangedExec(param), param => true);

            return m_selectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void SelectionListboxChangedExec(object param)
    {
        SelectionChangedEventArgs e = (SelectionChangedEventArgs)param;
        ListBox b = (ListBox)e.Source;
        CurrentSelection = (FilterOptions)b.SelectedItem;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    RelayCommand m_projectCheckedChanged;
    public ICommand ProjectListItemCheckedChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_projectCheckedChanged == null)
                m_projectCheckedChanged = new RelayCommand(param => ProjectListItemCheckedChangedExec(param), param => true);

            return m_projectCheckedChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ProjectListItemCheckedChangedExec(object param)
    {
        RoutedEventArgs e = (RoutedEventArgs)param;
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)e.Source;
        FilterOptions dataContext = (FilterOptions)checkBox.DataContext;

        if ((bool)checkBox.IsChecked)
            dataContext.AllFilterValues = true;
        else
        {
            dataContext.AllFilterValues = false;
        }

        //var expression = checkBox.GetBindingExpression(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty);
        //expression.UpdateSource();
    }
```

I really cant find the problem. Is there anyone who can help me? 
Your help will be much appreciated !!

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to do it with a command? bind the checkbox to a `BindingOption` class that internally notifies the parent `ViewModel`, this notification really doesn't belong in the view, but to the view-model.

The `ViewModel` isn't supposed to know that the view uses a CheckBox.

So what u should do have the individual options have a notifying `IsSelected` property bound to the `CheckBox`es, provide each of them with a reference to the parent `ViewModel`, and notify the parent when current `IsSelected` was changed. Doing this in the View, although you can find many way to do it, you're not supposed to, MVVM is about separating view-tasks from viewmodel-tasks.

This is way also gives you control on "Select all", "Deselect all" or "Invert selection" etc.

Comment: Even when I do not use commands, it is still not working.

I did bind everything correctly, but the problem still remains...

Comment: Well I think there has to be a bug because:

    private void SelectionListboxChangedExec(object param)
        {
            SelectionChangedEventArgs e = (SelectionChangedEventArgs)param;
            ListBox b = (ListBox)e.Source;            
            CurrentSelection = (FilterOptions)b.SelectedItem;
            CurrentSelection.ProjectName = "ba";
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSelection");
        }

Just works, but when I am binding it is not updating....

Comment: @JoshMulholland, I didn't exactly understand what is not updating, please extend your question with code and comment on it what doesn't work, please comment on here as well, so I get notified on your update. Thanks.